# Contents of settings.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

As can be seen from the contents of settings.gradle, this file should contain the information about modules in the project.

What's the difference between these two statements?

```
include ':ExternalModule1'
include 'ExternalModule2'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference in behaviour for the statements you mentioned since both of them mean the same thing, "include the specified module which is located right under the project's root".

The `:` sign does start making the difference though when it's used as module path separator, as stated in the docs of the `include` method:

> Adds the given projects to the build. Each path in the supplied list
>   is treated as the path of a project to add to the build. Note that
>   these path are not file paths, but instead specify the location of the
>   new project in the project heirarchy. As such, the supplied paths must
>   use the ':' character as separator.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the doc of the include method? I hit a dead end with the Android [settings.gradle](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/#settings-file) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is, that with the `:` you can dive deeper into a module.

```
include ':ParentProject:SubProject:SubModule'
```

That would be a valid include setting for a deeper structure. Therefore the separator `:`